# determine whether these polynomials span p2

Tags: linear-algebra

if $p1= 1+2x$, $p2=1-2x+4x^2$, $p3=2+4x^2$, $p4=4x-4x^2$...              hello i have tried this with 3 equation (p1,p2,p3) but now that i have 4 i am a bit lost. can u please help? i know i should do the determinant to do it but which equations should i use?

Comment: $\mathbb P_2$ is $3$-dimensional, so it takes only $3$ polynomials to span

Comment: so how do i do it?

Comment: See if $3$ of the $4$ span

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $p3=p1+p2$ and $p4=p1-p2$

Answer (score -1):

$p3=p1+p2$ and $p4=p1-p2$, so there are at most $2$ linearly independent polynomials here,

so they cannot span $\mathbb P_2$, which is $3$-dimensional.

If you must use determinants, note that $\begin{vmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 4 \\ 2 & 0 & 4\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1 & 2 & 0
\\1 & -2 & 4\\0 & 4 & -4\end{vmatrix}=0.$